# how to add a title and author in an \appendix?

Tags: formatting, koma-script, appendices, article

I am using a KOMA script class and I need to add an appendix at the end of my paper.

Problem is: I would like to have a title and an author part in the appendix, very much as the ones I have in the main document

Any ideas how can I do that? The following solution (using `\author{John Doe}` and `\maketitle` after `\appendix`) does not work

```
\documentclass[11pt,captions=nooneline,DIV=14, parskip=half]{scrartcl}


\begin{document}
\title{my title}

\author{John Doe}
\date{ }
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

intro

\appendix
\section{appendix}

% does not work unfortunately. Nothing appears
\author{John Doe}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You'll get more (and better) answers if you turn this into a Minimal Working Example.  Yes it's a bit more work on your end, but it saves all of your answerers that much work as well.

Comment: OK hold on one sec.

Comment: @Teepeemm done. Do you think you have an idea here? thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure.  Are you wanting the same author or a different one?  The `\author` command only sets the author internally; it doesn't typeset it.  `\maketitle` typesets the title; so you should at least try to run `\maketitle` again.

Comment: @Teepeemm: As far as I know `KOMA` classes (like `article` etc.) disable the `\maketitle` command after its first usage, i.e. another call of `\maketitle` does nothing at all. If the KOMA class is replaced by `article`, `\author{Jane Doe}` will print `Jane Doe` which means that `\author` has been changed to `\let\author\relax` etc. and is a design flaw, actually.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You are wrong. See my answer.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: I was only wrong with KOMA ... but since I don't use KOMA at all I can live with that ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already since KOMA-Script 3.12 (Beta from May 2013 or release from December 2013), all KOMA-Script classes support several titles inside the document. So you can simply use, e.g.,

```
\documentclass[11pt,captions=nooneline,DIV=14, parskip=half]{scrartcl}[2013/05/29]% Need at least an early state of KOMA-Script 3.12

\begin{document}
\title{my title}

\author{John Doe}
\date{ }
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

intro

\appendix

% does not work unfortunately. Nothing appears
\title{Appendix}
\author{John Doe}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

to generate an additional appendix title:

[image]